# How to create checkboxes on multiple pages in java iText PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, checkbox

I currently have a method that looks like this for making checkboxes on my pdf:

```
private static void createCheckbox(PdfWriter writer, float lowerLeftX, float lowerLeftY, float upperRightX, float upperRightY, String fieldName, boolean startChecked) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    RadioCheckField bt = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY, upperRightX, upperRightY), fieldName, "Yes");
    bt.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK);
    bt.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THIN);
    bt.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
    bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    bt.setChecked(startChecked);
    bt.setOptions(RadioCheckField.READ_ONLY);
    PdfFormField ck = bt.getCheckField();
    writer.addAnnotation(ck);
}
```

This lets me send in lower left X and Y coords and upper right X and Y coords in order to make a box.  This seems to work fine on the first page of a document where I create checkboxes.  If I try making them on later pages, they just don't appear.

Example: I make a PDF form some text on page one, make a new page, add more info plus checkboxes, make a new page, add more info and checkboxes.  That last page will not actually display checkboxes even if I use the same code for both pages with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a different name on each page. Field names are document-wide.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I just added the current page number to the end of the field names as the checkboxes were created.